# Obtain the power of the most powerful test from the following test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

$X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} f(x) $, i=1,2,...,n

$f(x)=\frac{\theta}{x^2}, \text{ } 0<\theta<x$

$H_0:\theta=\theta_0$
vs
$H_1:\theta=\theta_1 (>\theta_0)$

What will the power of the most powerful test deduced from it?